# Sitemesh binding with GroovyPagesTemplateEngine

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I am rendering some GSP files I have like this:

groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(file.text , file.name).make(model).writeTo(sw)

The gsp uses sitemesh via `<meta name="layout" content="main" /`>. Sometimes the objects I
put in the model are visible to the sitemesh template, most of the time they are not. Any ideas on making this work correctly?

Thanks

Comment: as a work around i was able to create/print the template in the view. This let sitemesh layouts work correctly for whatever reason.